# Выбрать строку из файла

Tags: python-3.x

Такой код печатает количество строк в файле:

```
lin = len(open('/home/kali/inferno.txt').readlines())
print(lin)
```

> 64

Как распечатать выбранную строку?

Comment: А какая строка выбрана? Сейчас код выводит количество строк. Какую строку хотите вывести?

Comment: Какой объект возвращает функция readlines? может быть, его использовать?

Comment: @MBo `open(...).readlines()` возвращает массив строк (Примерно тоже самое, что и `open(...).read().split('\n')`). Можно вывести все строки, можно вывести последнюю, но нам нужно вывести _выбранную строку_...

Comment: @mironovmeow Ну я, собственно, хотел автора побудить к размышлению

Comment: А я пытаюсь побудить автора к переформулированию вопроса

Comment: А надо побудить самостоятельно искать ответ на простой вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял то это делается как-то так:

```py
with open("/home/kali/inferno.txt") as f:
    print(f.readlines()[<НОМЕР ВЫБРАННОЙ СТРОКИ>])
```

Если не понятен такой синтаксис, то так будет понятнее:

```py
f = open("/home/kali/inferno.txt")
print(f.readlines()[<НОМЕР ВЫБРАННОЙ СТРОКИ>])
f.close()
```

Эти решения эквивалентны.

PS: Если номер строки слишком большой то вызывается `IndexError`

Comment: Да, но номер строки записан в переменной, нужно:
with open("/home/kali/inferno.txt") as f:
    print(f.readlines()[<значение переменной>])

Comment: @rockyou а откуда пользователь, написавший ответ будет это знать? Вам дали пример использования, если в вашем вопросе такой информации нет, то адаптируйте под ваши потребности. Как вы будете передавать номер строки, переменная, вычисления или хардкод - это дело десятое

Comment: Мне не понятен синтаксис в данном случае.

Comment: @rockyou Я правил ответ теперь будет понятней. И еще, если мой ответ вам помог то отметьте его как принятый (серая галочка слева).

Comment: если вам непонятен базовый синтаксис языка, то нужно взять учебник и расширить знания